# excel solver runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, solver

I'd like to solve a chemical equilibrium between 4 isomers with excel. For that I'd like to use the solver.
Now my problem is that I get a 'runtime error 1004'. These are my settings:

[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54L4i.png)

The first Kis are set values I calculated before.

The second Kis are calculated from x1 x2 x3 and x4 and should be equal to the first Kis (row 85)

x4 is calcualted from x1-3 x4=1-x1-x2-x3

Therefore I want to minimize the difference between the Kis of row 85 and row 86 (∆Ki, row 87) by changing x1,x2 and x3.

In solver I entered:
(see below)

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Here I tried to make it more clear
[both images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIL3p.png)

Comment: Your last two constraints (= 0), are you sure, these are correct?

Comment: What I would do is the following: Since you want to minimize your 3 delta_KI values at once. In another column, lets say in E5 you sum the delta_KI values. Then you use the solver on that cell with your first 3 constraints and elete the last two.

Comment: same error :/ (In addition, like this the constallation K1=0, K2=-K3 would be possible)

Comment: Versuche das mal so:
In Zelle E5 fügst du das hier ein `=ABS(B3-B4)+ABS(C3-C4)+ABS(D3-D4)` darauf hin im Solver dein Ziel als E5 festlegen. Dann nimmst du nur deine ersten 3 Nebenbedingungen und fügst noch 3 weitere hinzu und zwar $B$88 >= 0 usw. (Sodass die werte nicht negativ werden können) und lässt den Solver nochmal laufen. Wichtig das du deine letzten 3 Nebenbedinugen löschst, weil die nicht Sinnvoll sind.

Comment: leider geht es immernoch nicht

Comment: Kannst du mir mal die Formeln sagen, wie du die Werte für die KI berechnest?

Comment: Ich habe es mal probiert ohne Nebenbedingungen probiert. Da bekomme ich keinen Fehler, aber auch kein Ergebnis.
die oberen KI sind exp(∆G/-RT) (also konstant) die unteren x1/x2, x1/x3 und x1/x4

Comment: Was meinst du mit RT?

Comment: workaround: lineares Gleichungssystem -> Ax=b ->matlab.. so muss ich halt die werte abtippen. also falls dir noch was besseres einfällt bin ich trotzdem dankbar :) Andernfalls vielen Dank für deine Hilfe! RT Gaskonstante * Temp, in meinem Fall 8,314*1000

Comment: Schau dir mal die Lösung an. für mich hat das funktioniert.

Comment: Das müsste aber ein Nicht-Lineares-Gleichunsgsystem ergeben... oder Irre ich mich?

Comment: ich bekomme die gleichungen 0 = -Ki*x1 + xi mit 2<=i<=4 und 1=x1+x2+x3+x4. Leider wird das ergebnis in Matlab nicht sonderlich genau und ich komme auf andere Lösungen wie der Kollege unten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing the solver.xlam file in my german "de.lproj" directory by its equivalent in the "en.lproj" directory.
I also changed my system's language from german to english.
Not sure wich of both solved it, but it works perfectly fine now.

Thx anyway for your help!

EDIT: seems like the change of language did it

Answer (score 0):

I entered this formula in E5:

```
=ABS(B3-B4)+ABS(C3-C4)+ABS(D3-D4)
```

Used these [settings in the solver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYAv4.png)

And I got this [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UwDD.png)

Comment: I still get the same error :/ so it must be something else than the settings in the solver. strange